# redis sentinel out of sync with servers in a cluster

Tags: redis, master-slave, redis-sentinel

We have a setup with a number of redis (2.8) servers (lets say 4) and as many redis sentinels. On startup of each machine, we set a pre-select machine as master through the command line and all the rest as slaves of that. and the sentinels all monitor these machines. The clients first connect to the local sentinel and retrieve the master's IP address and then connect there.

This setup is trouble free most of the time but sometimes the sentinels go out of sync with servers. if I name the machines A,B,C and D - sentinels will think B is master while redis servers are all connected to A as the master. bringing down redis server on B doesnt help either. I had to bring it down and manually "Sentinel failover" on A to fix the issue. Question is 
1. What causes this to happen and whats the easiest and quickest way to fix this ?
2. What is best configuration - is there something better than this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time you should set a master is the first time. Once sentinel has taken over management of replication you should let it do it. This includes on restarts. Don't use the command line to set replication.  Let sentinel and redis manage it. This is why you're getting issues - you've told sentinel it is authoritative, but you are telling the Redis servers to ignore sentinel.

Sentinel stores the status in its Config file, so when it restarts it can resume the last configuration. So even on restart, let sentinel do it's job.

Also, if you have 4 servers (be specific, not "let's say") you should be running a quorum of three on your monitor statement in sentinel. With a quorum of two you can wind up with two masters

Comment: Thanks ! so basically the issue is that sentinels would try to start from a known configuration that they agree on while servers are told via the command line that they are in another specific configuration ? The issue is that we restart the four machines over every weekend. I would like us to restart with a new config after this restart. Would getting rid of the config file help ? Or should I just leave the sentinels to continue on ?

Comment: I would recommend letting sentinel do its thin, and remove the bits telling the servers who the master is. Restarting isn't an issue, and switching masters can result in lost data (if a slave is behind and you make it the master, for example), and the aforementioned problems. Whatever node was master before the restart has the most current data, so you'd want to select it anyway. With sentinel doing it you don't have to worry about it. Plus the configs on the local redis instances will still have the info anyway.